# iOS TV button menu & image

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tvos

I started a basic iOS TV project.. As you see in image I've created different system buttons and an image object. If I try it on simulator I can move from buttons with keyboard and also with TV Remote Controller without any code. Now, I would like to change the Image whenever I select any different buttons. for example: if I'm on Button1 I want display Image1, if I go to button6 I want display Image6 and so on...
but I can't find a way to make it possible (I know the button, the button state, outlet and action)...
can anyone help me? I would not start again from zero... I like the apple system buttons... thanks

[ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG0fu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the following method in your view controller to detect changes in focus. Then just look at the `nextFocusedView` and update your image as needed. You might want to set the `tag` property on the buttons and use a `switch` statement, but there are many ways to figure out which button is selected.

```
override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    guard let nextFocusedView = context.nextFocusedView,
          let previouslyFocusedView = context.previouslyFocusedView else {
        return
    }

    // Update image based on nextFocusedView
}
```